# Refresh a form and re-execute constructor code

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a way to refresh a form so that it executes all code in the constructor, I've tried with `Form.Refresh()`, `this.Invalidate()`, and even `Form.Reload()`.. Still doesen't run as it does the first time I start the application, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you just create a new form entirely?

Answer (score 12):

The constructor can't be executed twice. You can build a workaround by putting your constructor's code in a method and calling it when it's needed.

Example:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoStuff();
    }

    void DoStuff()
    {
        //Your code
    }

    void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: That, alone, won't be the same as a fresh form.  You'll also need to null out a lot of values that are never set at all in the constructor, you need to potentially wipe out information the user has entered into the form in some way, etc.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely try this out. So the constructor doesen't even execute twice when I reload the form..?

Comment: Servy is right. If you want a completely new Form it could be easier to just create a new one. @Jacco The constructor can be called only once in **any** type.